# Missing understanding in how to add SAML SSO to a react app

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, saml

I have a web app build with react. Now I need to secure it with da User Login. This login should use companys ADFS to perform a Single Sign On with SAML.

I have done some research on the web but now I am more confused than I was before.
If I understood right I have to create a backend server, for example in spring boot with Spring Security SAML. This server must provide a endpoint called login which is secured.

The react app has to call this endpoint and the user will be redirected to login or signed in via SSO.

Is my understandig right or did I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security SAML is a client-side SAML stack. This allows your app. to act as a SAML SP.

You need to add the stack to your app.

This can then talk to a SAML IDP. ADFS fills this role.

You don't have to create it, just configure it so it talks to your SAML SP.